# Heroku installation for Mac Catalina - needs to be updated. Workaround?

Tags: security, heroku, updates, macos-catalina

I cannot install Heroku command line for Mac OS - the heroku-pkg needs to be updated to meet Apple security requirements.  Is there a workaround?

[Heroku Pkg installer - Apple Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gePA1.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same problem. I fixed it by first installing homebrew via command line:

/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"

and then once that finishes paste this into the command line:

brew install heroku/brew/heroku

i hope it works for you!!